# Can i write java code which reloads one internet page?

Tags: java

I'm just wondering if I can write code which reloads an internet page for example in 5 seconds. I only know Java so, is it possible with this language?

Comment: What are you doing currently? What is the final objective? Do you want the page to be reloaded itself or downloaded after 5 min.

Comment: yes i want the page to be reloaded itself for example in 5 seconds, but i could not find the way that i should start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSP you can use

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"> //Refresh after 5 seconds
```

Also you can use [HttpServletResponse#setIntHeader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setIntHeader%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
<% response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5); %>//Refresh after 5 seconds
```

Comment: Put it inside `<head>`.You can find more information about meta-refresh tag on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

Comment: ohhhhh i found it thank you and kiss you kiss you kiss you my friend

Comment: If this works for you, be sure to mark the response as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look into the HttpURLConnection class. There are many examples of this.

Comment: one of my friend found a code from the web,but i do not know how can i use that                                                     <head>
...
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
...
</head>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with httpservlet. You can refresh a page with http header

```
response.setHeader("Refresh", "5; url=http://your.domain.com/page");
```

or by hml meta refresh. 
(code is not tested)